# Populate credentials in CredentialPicker class

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I'm using the CredentialPicker class to get login details from the user, and then storing those details into the system using the PasswordVault class. So far so good.

Is it possible then that after a credential has been stored, the CredentialPicker can be enabled to display a dropdown list of usernames, and when the user selects a username the password field is automatically populated? Both these username and password fields can be retrieved from the PasswordVault.

I suppose the next best thing to do would be to automatically populate the username and password fields for the last logged in user and display that to the user, but I can't seem to find any option in the CredentialPicker class to do so.

Are any of the above possible

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose the next best thing to do would be to automatically populate the username and password fields for the last logged in user and display that to the user, but I can't seem to find any option in the CredentialPicker class to do so.

I think this can be done by doing the following:

1. Each time you use `CredentialPicker`, store the resulting `CredentialPickerResult.Credentials` property value.
2. When you set up `CredentialPickerOptions`, set the `PreviousCredential` value to this value.

See [Programming Windows 8 Apps With HTML CSS and JavaScript](http://www.scribd.com/doc/126431216/330/The-Credential-Picker-UI) for more information.